# Scrollview doesn't scroll to the margin at the bottom

Tags: android-layout, scrollview

I have a simple layout as follows :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#D23456" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="800dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The background of the scrollview is pink and linear layout inside has the android icon image with a height of 800dp (that doesnt fit to the screen) . What I'm expecting to see is that imageview floats in a background of pink with a margin of 10dp in every sides (top,bottom,left,right).But when I scroll to the bottom, the scrollview doesn't scroll to the margin, so the bottom of the scroll is the imageview not the pink margin.

How can I prevent this? This makes the user think the page hasn't ended yet and makes him want to scroll more.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I later found out that ,a similar situation has already been answered in the following thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/16885601/1474471 by @olefevre.

Adding an extra LinearLayout that surrounds the current LinearLayout with a padding and removing the inner LinearLayout's layout-margin solved the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#D23456"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="800dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Just an FYI, it doesn't have to be a `LinearLayout`.  I am using a `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: this is the solution...it worked like a charm..! @Mehmet Katircioglu

Comment: As @mattblang has mentioned, for performance it's better to use a FrameLayout instead of the heavier Linear and Relative layouts.

Answer (score 19):

The solution posted by @Mehmet Katircioglu works well, but you can solve the problem simply changing the **android:layout_margin** to **android:padding**, without none extra view. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="#D23456"
      android:padding="10dp" >

      <!-- Your content (ImageView, buttons...) -->
  <LinearLayout/>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `android:fillViewport="true"` on the `ScrollView` may do it.

example in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819189/how-to-make-my-layout-able-to-scroll-down).

Comment: I'm aware of this property, but doesn't work in this case (try yourself). we might be missing something.