# ScrollView doesn't scroll all the way to the bottom

Tags: android

My `ScrollView` does not scroll all the way to the bottom, I have read a few similar questions here like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131962/scrollview-doesnt-scroll-to-the-bottom) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124680/scrollview-doesnt-scroll-to-the-margin-at-the-bottom) among others. I tried adding **10dp padding bottom** but it did not help. The image below shows how my problem looks

[image: notScrolled]

And the image below is how it is supposed to look (**Added 150dp padding bottom**)

[image: scrolled]

As you can see there is another item at the bottom. I also can't simply keep the **150 padding bottom** because the number of items being displayed in the list are being fetched from a database and may vary, therefore i would need to increase/decrease the **padding**

Here is my XML for the fragment

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/weekDisplayed">

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        app:layout_heightPercent="10%"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:background="@drawable/main_calendar_header_menu">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                app:layout_marginLeftPercent="3%"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:id="@+id/prevIcon"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="@mipmap/arrow_left"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="Placeholder"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/periodTextView"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            app:layout_marginRightPercent="3%"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/nextIcon"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@mipmap/arrow_right"/>

    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/daysContainer"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

                </RelativeLayout>


                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/shadow_middle"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/daysContainer"
                    android:id="@+id/shadowMiddle"/>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/shadowMiddle"
                    android:id="@+id/summaryContainer"
                    android:paddingBottom="150dp">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/commissionSummaryContainer"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_height="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/shadowBottom"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/commissionSummaryContainer"
                        android:background="@drawable/shadow_middle"/>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/absenceSummaryContainer"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/shadowBottom">

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

The `@+id/daysContainer`, `@+id/commissionSummaryContainer` and `@+id/absenceSummaryContainer` are the views where its children are being fetched and created dynamically.

Comment: Did you try to add inside the RelativeLayout (child of ScrollView) a dummy view (like a android.support.v4.widget.Space) with property alignParentBottom=true ?

Comment: Try giving `app:layout_heightPercent="90%"` to your scrollview

Comment: Instead of using PercentRelativeLayout use Relative layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Mehmet Kologlu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2707325/mehmet-kologlu) said, I gave my `ScrollView` a fixed height of `app:layout_heightPercent="80%"` instead of `wrap_content` and that solved my problem.