# RecyclerView scrollbar doesn't touch the bottom of the view

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack

The RecyclerView is fully scrolled down yet the scrollbar does not touch the bottom of the view.

```
   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/ordersList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

My XML and ViewHolder codes are very simple, there are no any complicated logic to confuse it this way.
This issues is exists in all Recyclerview lists on my app.
I now there were such a bug on android support library earlier, but now I use androidx.

Looking for any idea why can this happen.

[image: scrollbar doesn't reach bottom]

Comment: Do you check if you have any type of margin or padding set to any view that makes this effect?? See this post, has very similar problem and will be about this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131962/scrollview-doesnt-scroll-to-the-bottom

Comment: @Sergio yes I tried it's not the case, removing all paddings and margins doesn't help

Comment: Have you try to change the fixed size of the recyclerview and see the behaviour? If I don't see the rest of the layout is difficult to know...